Is there a general circuit implementation for the commutation matrix?
The commutation matrix $K^{(r,m)}$ is defined by
$
K^{(r,m)} = \sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j=1}^m (\boldsymbol{e}_{r,i} \boldsymbol{e}_{m,j}^T) \otimes (\boldsymbol{e}_{m,j} \boldsymbol{e}_{r,i}^T)
$
It also has the convenient property that $K^{(r,m)}(A\otimes B)K^{(n,q)}=B\otimes A$ where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{r\times q}$.
By playing around, I found the following:
$K^{(2,2)}=SWAP(0,1) \quad$ algassert 1
$K^{(2,4)}=SWAP(0,1)\,SWAP(1,2) \quad$ algassert 2
$K^{(4,2)}=SWAP(1,2)\,SWAP(0,1) \quad$ algassert 3
It seems that $K^{(r,m)}$ is implemented with purely $SWAP$ gates. This brings me to my question, is there a general circuit implementation for $K^{(r,m)}$?

The commutation matrix is usually just referred to as a $\text{SWAP}$ operator in quantum information, which for two Hilbert spaces of dimension $d_1=2^n$ and $d_2=2^m$ has the form,
\begin{align}
\text{SWAP} &= \sum_{i=1}^{d_1} \sum_{j=1}^{d_2} |i \rangle \langle j| \otimes |j \rangle \langle i| \\&= \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_n\in\{0,1\}} \sum_{j_1,\dots ,j_n\in\{0,1\}} |i_1,\dots,i_n \rangle \langle j_1,\dots j_m| \otimes |j_1,\dots,j_m \rangle \langle i_1,\dots,i_n|, \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $|i_k\rangle:= e_{2,i}$ in your notation. As the name of the operator suggests, it can indeed be expressed as a sequence of operators $\text{SWAP}(i,j)$ that swap the $i$-th and $j$-th qubits. This is easier to show diagramatically. Representing the qubit swap operator as this:
                                                                            
Then you can use Eq. (1) to draw $K^{(2,4)}$ like this:
                                                                  
on the right hand side you can see two qubit $\text{SWAP}(i,j)$ operators, recovering the first identity that you derived (the swap diagram reads left to right but the sequence of operators you multiply reads right to left!).
You can do this for any $\text{SWAP}$ operator between systems whose dimension is a power of two, e.g. $K^{(4, 16)}$:
                                                    
This decomposition is not unique, since there are a lot of ways to reach a given permutation.

Thank you @forky40! I just want to add the generalized equation that I was able to come up with based on your response. $K^{(2^n,2^m)}=\prod_{r=n-1}^{0} \prod_{q=0}^{m-1}SWAP(r+q,r+q+1)$.
